# How can I play a haptic feedback while AvCapture Session is running?

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, avaudiosession, vibration, haptic-feedback

When my Avcapture session is running and ready to record a video , I cannot play and audio files, vibrate or play any haptic feedback? I only found a solution for objective c but not swift.

Objective C Solution : [Using vibrate and AVCaptureSession at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425154/using-vibrate-and-avcapturesession-at-the-same-time)

Comment: sigh... I'm struggling with the same issue - I have AVCaptureSession with live preview and I also want to provide haptic feedbacks when user taps on buttons. If I add audioInput to my AVCaptureSession then I'm not able to produce haptic feedback at all. I tried to to add audioInput just before starting to record and to remove just after stopping but modifying configuration of the capture session leads to live preview hiccups (it becomes completely black for a fraction of a second). And I still have no idea how Snapchat and Instagram do this trick.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out Daniyar?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009624/928911

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording` from iOS13 and later.

```
try session.setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using microphone in the `AVCaptureSession`, the haptic feedback will not play.

Apple tries to prevent the vibration from disrupting the microphone capture. This is noted in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405202-audioservicesplayalertsound

If you are not recording from the mic yet (as you said you are just in a "ready state"), then a solution is to delay adding the mic until you want to start recording.

Of course, while recording, you still may not play any haptic feedback.

Answer (score 0):

session.setAllowHapticsAndSystemSoundsDuringRecording(true) is good for me!!
I'm using AudioQueueServices + CHHapticEngine