# Haptic Feedback Calls Listener on Android

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering if there was a way to listen to (or directly redirect) the haptic feedback calls of the android device, coming from any app and from the system itself,

Basically I want to build an app that allow me to get the information everytime something trigger haptic,
Is there any way to do so?
I'd like to be able to then redirect it through bluetooth communication (that I know how to do),

Have an awesome day,

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450038/ios-haptic-feedback-not-firing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting or listening to haptic feedback calls across all apps and the system on Android and iOS devices could potentially raise privacy and security concerns. Both platforms prioritize app isolation and may not provide direct, standardized ways to achieve this. It's recommended to focus on integrating haptic feedback within your app using the provided APIs. While Bluetooth communication sounds feasible, intercepting system-level events might be challenging due to security restrictions.

Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).