# Sequence of haptic feedback impacts

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, haptic-feedback

I have a property
`@Published var shouldAnimateChatTabIcon: Bool`.
In the view's modifier `.onChange(of: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon)`, based on **shouldAnimateChatTabIcon** value, I want to execute a function and generate continuous haptic feedback. I want to generate repeating sequence of 3 haptic impacts:

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.light.impactOccurred()
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.medium.impactOccurred()
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.heavy.impactOccurred()
```

This sequence should repeat until **shouldAnimateChatTabIcon** is false.
Between every impact there should be **delay of 0.8 seconds** and the same delay should be between both sequences.

I thought of using three `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` executors with no success though - there was only one impact or none.
The same outcome was when trying to use `async/await with Task` inside `.onChange` as @jnpdx suggested

```
.onChange(of: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon) { _, shouldStart in
            if shouldStart {
                Task {
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 800_000_000)
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 800_000_000)
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy).impactOccurred()
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 800_000_000)
                }
            }
        }
```

I searched other posts and found out that haptic feedback does not work when using microphone which was exactly what I was trying to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450237/14793963.

Tried without microphone usage and @jnpdx solution worked fine. Is there any way to avoid this restriction and trigger haptic feedback during microphone usage?

Comment: Use async/await. `action(); try? Task.sleep(...); action2();` etc

Comment: @jnpdx Unfortunately this didn't work. Maybe I misunderstood your suggestion - updated my question.

Comment: @jnpdx another edit. Your solution works fine but maybe you know how to trigger haptic feedback during microphone usage?

Comment: I would assume they disable this since it would end up getting recorded (at least when using the default mic)